# Strange behavior after deleting *.pyc and rerunning .py script

Tags: python, caching

I have three modules as:

`one.py`:

```
def abc():
    print "Heeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiioooooooooo"
```

`two.py`:

```
import one

def defg():
    one.abc()
```

`three.py`:

```
import os
from time import sleep

import two
two.defg()

sleep(20)


directory = os.listdir('.')

for filename in directory:
    if filename[-3:] == 'pyc':
        print '- ' + filename
        os.remove(filename)
```

I have three doubts.

When I run `three.py` for the first time `one.pyc` and `two.pyc` will be created. I can see it since I gave 20 sec delay. After executing the statement `os.remove(filename)`, they get removed. Until here its fine.

Again without closing the IDLE as well as the script, I ran `three.py`. This time no `.pyc` file was created. Why is this so?

If I close IDLE as well as the script, `.pyc` will be created as before.

1. Why the compiled code is not getting created again and again?
2. Also, if I make a change in `one.py` it will not be shown if I run without closing the shells. I need a solution for this also.
3. Third doubt is if the compiled code is getting deleted first time itself, then how the second run gives the same result without `.pyc`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.pyc` is not getting created again because there is a reference to your imported module in code. When it is re-run, this reference is used.

This is why the `.pyc` is not generated again, and also why the extra changes you make are not getting run.

You can either remove all references and call a garbage collect, or use the built in `reload()` function on the modules. e.g.:

```
reload(three)
```

Comment: Thank you. 
So when the shell is closed new reference comes to play ?
Anyway I want to avoid reload() How to remove all references and call a garbage collect ?

Comment: sys.modules always retains a reference, so you can't cause a module to go away like that, short of manually fiddling sys.modules, which is fraught with difficulty. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module

Comment: How i have done things before, not claiming the best implementation. import three; import sys,gc; del three # remove the local reference; del sys.modules["three"] # removes import; gc.collect() # make sure everythings tidyed up; import three # new .pyc

Answer (score 1):

I think that IDLE is caching the bytecode within its own Python process, so it doesn't need to regenerate the it each time the file is run.

Comment: Hmm, yes, what Nathan said :)

Answer (score 1):

> Edit ~/.bashrc and add this shell function to it
>
> > $ cd ; pyclean

```
pyclean () {
        find . -type f -name "*.py[co]" -delete
        find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -delete
}
```