# delete *.pyc continuation

Tags: python, operating-system, sys

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755694/delete-pyc), I have a new question:

What is happening internally in `os.remove(module_name)` and `del sys.modules["module_name"]`?

Comment: No. Either edit your original post or reword this into an actual question

Comment: You should tell what you really want to do? Delete .pyc files is generally not needed so why do you want to do this?

Comment: -1: No use case for this.  It doesn't matter under any conceivable circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that `os.remove(module_name)` will remove a file from the filesystem.  `del sys.modules["module_name"]` will remove a module from the cache of previously loaded modules that the current Python interpreter is maintaining.

In Python, when you import a module, the interpreter checks to see if there is a `.pyc` file of the same name as the `.py` file you are trying to import.  If there is, and if the `.py` file has not changed since the `.pyc` file has been imported, then Python will load the `.pyc` file (which is significantly faster).

If the `.pyc` file does not exist, or the `.py` file has been changed since the `.pyc` file was created, then the `.py` file is loaded and a new `.pyc` file is created.  (It is worth noting that simply running a Python file, say `test.py` will *not* cause a `test.pyc` to be created.  Only `import`ing modules causes this to happen.)

`sys.modules` is another matter entirely.  In order to speed up code which imports the same module twice, Python maintains a list of the modules that have been imported during the current interpreter session.  If the module being imported is in `sys.modules`, then the cached version will be read (neither `.py` nor `.pyc` files will be checked for on the disk).  Python provides a builtin function [`reload()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) which allows you to bypass the module cache and force a reload from disk.

To get more information on Python's module system, see the docs on [modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files).

Answer (score 2):

I start a lot of apps like this

```
import os

os.system('attrib +H *.pyc /S')
```

On windows this hides any visible compiled files when the app starts - they give me the pips.

Comment: Dear god.. You're a genius! I get the hibigeebies by the chaos they create in my project structure!

Answer (score 1):

my oneliner for this job:

```
find . -name *.pyc |xargs rm
```

NB: You need Linux (or Unix-like OS)